# Ошибка при запуске проекта в Wavemaker

Tags: tomcat

Возникает ошибка
Run failed: FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /

Я так понял это связано с apache tomcat, но что чинить не знаю.
Запускаю на Win7

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что проекты wavemaker лежат по адресу
C:\Users\Админ\Documents\WaveMaker

Папка админ переименованию не поддается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, проблема решена. Все из-за кириллических символов в пути